# How do I open developer tools on iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am wanting to open **developer tools** on an iOS simulator

I have taken the following steps, on a 2016 MacBook running **macOS Sierra 10.12.1** and don't know how to get any further:

- I have Xcode installed
- I create a new playground
- Right click on the Xcode dock icon and click Open Developer Tool > Simulator
- I now have an iOS simulator running whichever device I need, in my case iPhone 6 running IOS 10.0

Now I am wondering what steps do I take to debug, and inspect elements on a webpage as I would in Safari or Chrome developer tools?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Open Safari and go to Preferences. Under the Advanced tab, at the bottom, you'll see "Show Develop menu in menu bar". Make sure that is checked like in the image below.

[image: advanced preferences]

Once that is checked, you'll see a new menu bar item named "Develop" between "Bookmarks" and "Window" in Safari's menu. Under the Develop menu, select "Simulator" and then select the site you want to debug. A new window with the developer tools will then pop up:

[image: developer tools]

Comment: Under Develop > Simulator I get `No Inspectable Applications`

Comment: Actually that was just because I hadn't opened a webpage in Safari on the simulator yet, once I loaded the page to debug up it was all good. thanks

Comment: Site is greyed out

Comment: Develop > Simulator is no longer part of Safari, instead download and use "Safari Technology Preview" https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

Comment: To clarify - you can still get something that calls itself "web inspector" by following these instructions - but there's no "Elements" tab, so you can't actually inspect.

Comment: As of my writing of this comment, connecting to Safari tabs opened in an iOS simulator is offered in the Safari Technology Preview for macOS, not the bundled Safari.

Answer (score 16):

Download https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Open the website you want on your simulator.

On "Safari Technology Preview", under

`Develop > Simulator --- [SimulatorName] >`  select your website from the list.

Comment: 1. Open simulator from xcode first; 2. only afterwards open safari (restart it if already open). "Simulator" menu magically appears only when the simulator is already open. very intuitive...

Comment: why do you need Safari Technology Preview? Safari can do the same job.

Answer (score 11):

If you are on a mac, press `CMD` + `G` while running the Simulator on XCode. This will allow you to `Inspect element` like you can on a web browser.

To hide the menu, press `CMD` + `D`.

It looks like the most accepted answer incorrectly assumes the asker is wondering about Safari Simulator, not XCode Simulator.

Comment: `CMD` + `G` doesn't work for me. What works for me is `CMD` + `D`. This opens the developer menu from which I can show the inspector and hide the inspector etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using React Native then you can install [`react-devtools`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-devtools) globally and access devtools that way. To do this:

1. Install it by running `npm install -g react-devtools` from your terminal
2. Run `react-devtools` from your terminal
3. Make sure your app is running in the simulator
4. Open the in-app developer menu in the simulator by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

You should now see the components list from the React Devtools Electron app.

Comment: #4 may be different now.
Instead of [cmd]+[D] it may be [ctrl][cmd][Z] (Shake)

Answer (score 3):

**Early 2024, MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1, Safari Version 17.2.1:**

**Steps:**

1. Enable the *Develop* menu in Safari.

   To do this, open Safari, then click on the *Safari* menu, and then click on *Settings*:
   [image: Safari menu]

   In the Settings dialog, go to the *Advanced* tab, and enable *Show features for web developers*:
   [image]

   This will enable a menu item called *Develop* in the Safari menu bar:
   [image]

2. Quit Safari, and then restart it.
   [image]

3. Open the Developer Tools of the simluator.

   To do this, assuming you have your Xcode simulator already open, click on the Develop menu item in Safari. You should see your simulator in the list. Click on any of your simluator's webviews (e.g., *localhost --* in the following image).
   [image]

   You should now see your simlulator's Developer Tools window.
   [image]