# Call backend server using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building my first application in cordova, using html, css, and javascript. what I am trying to do right now is, on button click, call the local server, and have it log something, just so I know it works. but, even that isn't working. so what I am trying to do is below:

index.html

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="login-box">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form>
              <div class="user-box">
                <input type="text" name="" required="">
                <label>Username</label>
              </div>
              <div class="user-box">
                <input type="password" name="" required="">
                <label>Password</label>
              </div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <button onclick="submitButton()">Submit Function</button>  
            </form>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

and then in my `index.js` file, I have this:

```
 function submitButton() {
  const url ='http://localhost:6969/test';
const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
}


  fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers: headers})
  .then((res) => {
     return res.json()
})
}
```

and in my server:

```
 app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log("this is actually pretty cool, if it worked!")
  })
```

what am I doing wrong? am I missing something on the JS side, or maybe in cordova?

Comment: are you getting any error? can you insepect and check any errors on console

Comment: Please explain _that isn't working_. It doesn't call to **http://localhost:6969/test** or called but response in error? (HTTP status?, error message?) Or it does called to that URL but response nothing?

Comment: how is your app.js looks?

Comment: @vee see that's the thing, I have no clue, because I am testing using the iOS sdk, and I am trying to hit the ` localhost:6969/test` endpoint when the button is clicked. the only way I can tell that the endpoint is being hit is if it logs it in the console of my sever, but it isn't doing that. that's where the issue lies, I think

Comment: Are you running it in browser, as Electron app or on iOS/Android emulator/device? When calling from Android/iOS you need to use your ip address/hostname instead of localhost.

Comment: @santhosh my `app.js` is configured normally as you would for a node.js app, I've done it probably nearly 100 times. and it has one single, simple post function that I am trying to reach by using the fetch command. the sever is running on localhost:6969, and I am trying to `post` to the route

Comment: @MateuszKrawczyk using iOS simulator at the moment. how would I call from my local ip/hostname?

Comment: ifconfig, to find out the system ip address

Comment: @roger from commandline/terminal run command ```ifconfig``` and find your inet addr (but not 127.0.0.1, just the other one). Then replace in code localhost with this ip address.

Comment: @MateuszKrawczyk okay so once I do that, how do I access the localhost route? so in the url, I put `000.000.00.00`, and then how do I access the route `/test` on `localhost:6969/test`?

Comment: @roger http://000.000.00.00:6969/test or https://000.000.00.00:6969/test

Comment: @roger but you need also to check if your backend serwer is well configured, so try to open this url in your browser.

Comment: Please try to enable debug on your IOS simulator. I'm not sure what it is because I was never use it before but please try at least one of these. [1](https://adaptivejs.mobify.com/v2.0/docs/debug-on-ios-devices-and-the-ios-simulator/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455862/how-do-i-open-developer-tools-on-ios-simulator). This will be you a lot better debug IOS device.

Comment: @MateuszKrawczyk thanks for your advice. I ran the ip like you mentioned above in the browser, and it worked no problem, configured properly. But then I put it back into that fetch in my index.js inside my cordova, and it doesn't work! I have no clue what the issue is, so frustrating

Comment: @roger Set firewall rule on your PC (as server) to allow incoming to this port.

Comment: @roger try to run web browser (Safari) on this simulator and open this address

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you update your **fetch API** in submitButton to this?

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  // body: JSON.stringify(data), // you can just skip this if all you want is to test the API
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch